# ExcelWorksheet.UsedRange is counting wrong if file has empty rows on top

Tags: c#, excel

I have c# windows application that is reading files content. I wanted to extract values from used rows only.

I am using this code:

```
int rows = ExcelWorksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count;
```

Everything works fine. Except when I have empty rows on top, the counting will be incorrect.

-File has no special characters, formula or such. Just plain text on it.

-The application can read excel xls and xlsx with no issue if the file has no empty rows on top.

Comment: What you mean _counting wrong_?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, now I've realized I'm doing it all wrong. Of course it will not read all of my `UsedRange.Rows`  because in my `for` loop, I am starting the reading always on the first row. So I get the `((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)(ExcelWorksheet.UsedRange)).Row;` as a starting point of reading

This code works:

```
int rows = ExcelWorksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count;
int fRowIndex = ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)(ExcelWorksheet.UsedRange)).Row;

 int rowCycle = 1;

for (int rowcounter = fRowIndex; rowCycle <= rows; rowcounter++)
{   
  //code for reading        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of read Excel row-by-row, better to get it in C# as a Range, and then handle it as

```
Sheet.UsedRange.get_Value()
```

for whole UsedRange in Sheet. Whenever you'd like to get a part of UsedRange, do it as

```
Excel.Range cell1 = Sheet.Cells[r0, c0];
Excel.Range cell2 = Sheet.Cells[r1, c1];
Excel.Range rng = Sheet.Range[cell1, cell2];
var v = rng.get_Value();
```

You well know size of **v** in C# memory from the values of [r1-r0, c1-c0]